# MySQL - selecting where all other columns = 0

Tags: mysql, chemistry

Suppose you have a table with many property fields, such as:

```
id
datetime
q
a
c
d
.
.
.
(etc)
```

where q,a,c,d etc denote an *indefinite number of int fields whose names are generated (also created at runtime)*

How do you select with the constraint that some specific fields are a specific number and all others are 0?

(for example) a=1, c=5, and all others are 0?

---

Update:

I guess what i'm asking for is if there is some "holistic" function or something where i can just go "WHERE ALL OTHERS = 0" (or something like that).

The issue with normalizing is that even after the join, I still have to check for both the specific non-zero values as well as whether all other fields (or the normalized field) is 0.

---

Concrete application:

table of chemical compounds

```
id
name
C
Fe
Cl
H
.
.
.
(etc - fields are added when new compound insert contains elements not listed)
```

example row:

```
name = Hydrochloric acid
C = 0
Fe = 0
Cl = 1
H = 1
.
.
. 
(everything else = 0)
```

The problem with having a simple `SELECT * FROM table WHERE H=1 AND Cl = 1` is that it also includes the other cases such as C Cl H (which even though it has C=1, it's selected because Cl and H are both 1 as well)

This is why I'm trying to figure out how to select it where all other fields are 0!

Comment: Wait, you're altering the table potentially every time the page is loaded?

Comment: How/where are you building this statement?

Comment: the alter if field does not exist is a separate statement. the insert is another statement.

Comment: ideally, i'd like to be able to use something like "where all others = 0". added more explanatory material, including concrete example.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a realistic situation. You will never have a indefinite number of int fields because You can't just modify a table without the ALTER statement (only at runtime). At least, you shouldn't.

Comment: well, that's exactly what i'm doing: i'm modifying the table using ALTER at runtime

Comment: so It's easy handle it. Just add a new string every time you modify the table, and then check it out like this: e.g. var string = "c=0"; "SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE WHERE a=1 and b=5 and " + "string" (In case you add the column "c")

Comment: i'm trying to avoid having to explicitly declare the 0 ones... see updated question for the concrete example

Answer (score 1):

You can't actually have an indefinite number of columns in a table - you're limited to a *definite* quantity. In that case, you just use:

```
... where a = 1 and c = 5 and q = 0 and b = 0 and d = 0 and ...
```

If you simply meant that the quantity is definite but the number of columns *used* by your application may change, then the query will need to be generated at runtime as well, using the same information. For example, if `d` was not used at runtime, it would be left off the query.

But this is a very badly designed table and you should consider normalising it better, such as shifting those attributes to a separate table (one attribute per row in this new table) and linking them back to the original table with the `id` field, such as:

```
BaseTable:
    id          integer        primary key
    datetime    timestamp
OtherTable:
    id          integer        references BaseTable(id)
    attribute   char(1)
    text        varchar(50)
    primary key (id,attribute)
```

This sort of schema will allow arbitrary attributes on each `id`.

---

Based on your comments that you're altering the table based on some external factor, I think that's what we in the DBA world would call an "interesting" design decision :-)

I would strongly advise against that but, if you see fit to ignore that advice, you can get at the metadata in most DBA implementations.

For example, MySQL has a [`COLUMNS` table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/columns-table.html) in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` schema taht you can use to enumerate all the columns for a given table. Using that, you could dynamically construct a valid SQL statement based on an arbitrarily complex table.

Not saying that's a *good* idea, just that it's possible.

Comment: i guess what i'm asking for is if there is some "holistic" function or something where i can just go "WHERE ALL OTHERS = 0" (or something like that)  ... the problem with normalizing is that i still have to check for the cases where all others are 0, but then i need an extra join

Comment: There's no holistic function in standard SQL nor do I know of any extension for this in any of the vendor-specific implementations I follow.

Comment: i guess i'm not seeing how to normalize it so that the resulting select condition becomes easier. (See updated question above for concrete example)

Answer (score 0):

You construct something like this:

```
WHERE a=1
  AND c=5
  AND d=0
  AND e=0
  ...
```

or this:

```
WHERE (a, c, d, e, ...) =
      (1, 5, 0, 0, ...)
```

---

There is nothing like:

```
WHERE ALL OTHERS = 0
```

If you are repeatedly changing the table structure, you should dynamically change the query too. But this not a good design. You should normalize the table (probably by splitting the table into 2 tables and changing the repeated columns into one column, so the data goes from many columns to one column but many rows).

---

**Update after the OP's edit**

Possible normalization for the chemical compounds - elements:

```
Compound
--------
CompoundId   Int          Primary Key
Name         Varchar(250) Unique
...other stuff

Element
-------
ElementCode  Char(2)      Primary Key
Name         Varchar(50)  Unique 

Structure
---------
CompoundId   Int 
ElementCode  Char(2) 
Ratio        Int
Primary Key (CompoundId, ElementCode) 
Foreign Key (CompoundId)
  References Compound(CompoundId)
Foreign Key (ElementCode)
  References Element(ElementCode)
```

with sample data:

```
CompoundId  Name 
------------------------------
 1          Hydrochloric acid
 2          Water
 3          Glucose

ElementCode  Name 
---------------------
 H           Hydrogen
 C           Carbon
 O           Oxygen 
 Cl          Chlorium 

CompoundId  ElementCode  Ratio 
------------------------------
 1           H            1
 1           Cl           1 
 2           H            2
 2           O            1
 3           H            12
 3           C            6
 3           O            6
```

Comment: i guess what i'm asking for is if there is some "holistic" function or something where i can just go "WHERE ALL OTHERS = 0" (or something like that)